# Unable to start xinetd service though it is installed

Tags: networking, xinetd, inetd

I already installed `xinetd` but when I run:

```
service xinetd start
```

I get:

> start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.791" (uid=1000 pid=16012 comm="start xinetd ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")

I have added a service `rsh` by adding this file

```
cat > /etc/xinetd.d/shell << "EOF" &&

service shell
{
  disable        = no
  socket_type    = stream
  wait           = no
  user           = root
 instances      = UNLIMITED
 flags          = IDONLY
 log_on_success += USERID
 server          = /usr/sbin/in.rshd

}
EOF
```

I wish to use a system as a server, by using service `rsh` start. Right now I get back an answer as: `unknown job`.

What should I do?

Comment: First, use `sudo service xinetd restart` to gain the neede privilege. then check if the config file is actually there `cat /etc/xinetd.d/shell` and read by checking the output of xinetd in `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: I have a doubt, I have created /etc/xinetd.d/rsh file I don't have cat /etc/xinetd.d/shell. should I create file in the name of services present in /etc/services file only? Is it possible to act as a server by using service start rshd? I have already stored the names of clients in /HOME/.rhosts file. Should I also ensure that rsh is present in /etc/securetty file to start a server?